# React Memo not rendering the component even after state is changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react.memo

I used React.memo to memoize a component. Since React.memo checks value by reference, I used a compare function that compares previous props and updated props and pass this function as a callback of React.memo.

The thing is, I used a custom hook that contains the data. This hook is called in the parent component and the component I want to memoize is the child component. When the state changes, the first argument of compare function of React.memo is showing me the updated value. The state is getting changed in a different component but I am passing that state in to the child component then why it is showing me updated state (which is passed as a prop).

Here is the parent component: (Board)

```
    const data = useRef({ participant: { board: null, card: null }, board: null });

    // Refs for participants
    const participantsModal = useRef();

    // Refs for adding board
    const addBoardModal = useRef();
    const boardInput = useRef();

    // Refs for adding a new task
    const addCardModal = useRef();
    const piority = useRef();
    const taskName = useRef();

    // Refs for comments
    const commentModal = useRef();

    // ------------- This is the custom hook --------------- //
    const [boardData, setBoardData] = useBoardData(); 
    // ----------------------------------------------------- //
    const [newTaskParticipants, setNewTaskParticipants] = useState([{ name: "Hamza Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Rahim Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Khuzaima Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Tony Stark", checked: false }, { name: "Bruce Wayne", checked: false }]);
    const [addRemoveParticipants, setAddRemoveParticipants] = useState([{ name: "Hamza Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Rahim Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Khuzaima Nawab", checked: false }, { name: "Tony Stark", checked: false }, { name: "Bruce Wayne", checked: false }]);
    const [participantsList, setParticipantsList] = useState([]);
    const [commentCard, setCommentCard] = useState({ card: 0, board: 0 });

    const removeBoardHandler = (index, e) => setBoardData(boardData.filter((_, i) => i !== index));

    // <========= Functions to trigger modals ==========> //
    const triggerCommentsModal = useCallback((e) => {
        const element = e.target.closest(".card");
        const card = Number(element.id.split("-")[1]);
        const board = Number(element.closest(".board").id.split("-")[1]);
        setCommentCard({ card: card, board: board });
        commentModal.current.triggerModal();
    }, [])

    const triggerParticipantsModal = useCallback((e) => {
        participantsModal.current.triggerModal();
        data.current.participant = { board: e.target.closest(".board").id.split("-")[1], card: e.target.closest(".card").id.split("-")[1] }
        const participants = boardData[data.current.participant.board].cards[data.current.participant.card].participants;
        setParticipantsList(participants);
        setAddRemoveParticipants(addRemoveParticipants.map(value => participants.includes(value.name) ? { ...value, checked: true } : { ...value, checked: false }));
        console.log(data.current)
    }, [addRemoveParticipants, boardData]);

    const triggerAddCardModal = useCallback((e) => {
        addCardModal.current.triggerModal();
        data.current.board = e.target.closest(".board");
    }, []);

    const triggerAddBoardModal = useCallback(() => addBoardModal.current.triggerModal(), []);

    // <========= Functions performing functionality on saving button =========> //

    // <========= For adding a new board =========> //
    const createNewBoard = () => {
        const obj = { id: Math.random().toString(36).slice(2), title: boardInput.current.value, cards: [] };
        setBoardData([...boardData, obj]);
        addBoardModal.current.triggerModal();
    };

    // <========= For adding a new task =========> //
    const createNewTask = () => {
        const boardIndex = Number(data.current.board.id.split("-")[1]);
        const participantsArray = newTaskParticipants.filter(value => value.checked).map(value => value.name);
        const newBoardData = boardData.map((value, i) => {
            if (i === boardIndex) {
                value.cards.push({ text: taskName.current.value, piority: piority.current === "Low Piority" ? 0 : piority.current === "High Piority" ? 2 : 1, participants: participantsArray })
            };
            return value;
        });
        setBoardData(newBoardData);
        setNewTaskParticipants(newTaskParticipants.map(value => {
            value.checked = false;
            return value;
        }));
        addCardModal.current.triggerModal();
    };

    // <========= For adding/removing participants from a task =========> //
    const manuplateParticipants = () => {
        participantsModal.current.triggerModal();
        const participants = addRemoveParticipants.filter(value => value.checked).map(value => value.name);
        setBoardData(boardData.map((value, i) => {
            if (i === Number(data.current.participant.board)) {
                value.cards[data.current.participant.card].participants = participants;
            }
            return value;
        }));
    };

    return (
        <AnimatePresence>
            <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: 0.5 }} className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 flex grow flex-col items-end md:w-[90%] w-10/12 h-screen pt-20 px-6 bg-violet-100 overflow-auto">
                {/* Modal of comments */}
                <Modal ref={commentModal} heading="Comments" buttonText="Close" onSave={() => commentModal.current.triggerModal()}>
                    <div className='w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-2 py-3'>
                        <div className='w-11/12 rounded-md space-y-1'>
                            <p><span className='font-bold'>Task:</span> This is a new world :D</p>
                            <p><span className='font-bold'>Details:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr className='bg-gray-300 w-[95%]' />
                        <div className='w-8/12'>
                            <div className='max-h-80 space-y-2 overflow-y-auto mb-4'>
                                {boardData && boardData[commentCard.board]?.cards[commentCard.card]?.chats?.map((chat, i) => <CommentCard key={i} name={chat.name} dateTime={chat.dateTime} text={chat.text} />)}
                            </div>
                            <div className='w-full flex items-center justify-between space-x-2'>
                                <UserCircle buttonClassName="cursor-default" />
                                <MessageInput placeholder="Enter your comment ..." type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
                {/* Modal of adding/remove participant for specific cards button */}
                <Modal ref={participantsModal} heading="Assign/Dismiss Participants" buttonText="Save changes" onSave={manuplateParticipants}>
                    <div className='flex justify-between grow w-full p-3 space-x-4'>
                        <div className='relative w-1/2 space-y-2'>
                            <h2 className='lg:text-lg md:text-base text-sm font-semibold'>Add/Remove Participants</h2>
                            <MultiSelectDropdown buttonText="Select Participants" state={addRemoveParticipants} setState={setAddRemoveParticipants} />
                            <div className='flex flex-wrap grow max-h-32 overflow-auto'>
                                <AnimatePresence>
                                    {addRemoveParticipants.map((value, i) => value.checked && <UsernameTag state={addRemoveParticipants} setState={setAddRemoveParticipants} key={i} name={value.name} />)}
                                </AnimatePresence>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='w-px my-2 bg-slate-400'></div>
                        <div className='w-2/4 flex flex-col space-y-2'>
                            <h3 className='lg:text-lg md:text-base text-sm font-semibold'>Participants List</h3>
                            <div className='border border-slate-500 rounded-md flex flex-col items-center justify-start grow max-h-44 w-full overflow-y-auto'>
                                {participantsList.map((value, i) => <UserSmall key={i} name={value} />)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
                {/* Modal of adding a new task to the board */}
                <Modal ref={addCardModal} heading="Add a new Task" buttonText="Save Changes" onSave={createNewTask}>
                    <div className='flex md:flex-row flex-col justify-between grow p-3 w-full md:space-x-4'>
                        <div className='flex md:w-1/2 w-full flex-col space-y-4'>
                            <Input labelClassName="p-0 md:p-1" text="Name" reference={taskName} />
                            <div className='w-full flex items-center md:pl-1 space-x-4 relative'>
                                <span>Piority</span>
                                <DropDown options={["Low Piority", "Medium Piority", "High Piority"]} buttonText="Select Piority" btnCSS="w-40" choosePiority={piority} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='w-px my-2 bg-slate-400 '></div>
                        <div className='relative md:w-1/2 space-y-2 flex flex-col'>
                            <div className='flex items-center space-x-4 w-full'>
                                <span className=''>Add Participants</span>
                                <div className='w-2/3'>
                                    <MultiSelectDropdown btnCSS="sm:w-3/4 md:w-full" buttonText="Select Participants" state={newTaskParticipants} setState={setNewTaskParticipants} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex flex-wrap max-h-20 overflow-auto'>
                                <AnimatePresence>
                                    {newTaskParticipants.map((value, i) => value.checked && <UsernameTag state={newTaskParticipants} setState={setNewTaskParticipants} key={i} name={value.name} />)}
                                </AnimatePresence>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
                {/* Modal for adding a new board */}
                <Modal ref={addBoardModal} heading="Add a new Board" buttonText="Save Changes" onSave={createNewBoard}>
                    <div className='flex justify-start items-center w-full grow px-4'>
                        <Input text="Board Name" className="w-[85%]" reference={boardInput} />
                    </div>
                </Modal>
                <div className="w-full py-5 mb-3 text-3xl text-gray-500 px-3">Studio Board</div>
                <div className='flex space-x-4 h-[85%] min-h-[28rem] overflow-x-auto w-full px-3'>
                    <AnimatePresence>
// --------------------------------- This is the child component I am talking about -------------------------------- //
                        {boardData?.length > 0 ? boardData.map((value, i) => <CardHolder comments={triggerCommentsModal} addTaskHandler={triggerAddCardModal} triggerModal={triggerParticipantsModal} key={value.title} id={value.id} index={i} title={value.title} card={value.cards} removeBoard={removeBoardHandler} changeData={setBoardData} data={boardData} />) : <h1>No boards</h1>}
                    </AnimatePresence>
                </div>
                <div className='fixed bottom-5 right-5 bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-400 to-indigo-300 w-10 h-10 md:w-14 md:h-14 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center hover:brightness-110 active:brightness-90 z-50' onClick={e => triggerAddBoardModal()}><FaPlus className='text-white scale-150 p-1 md:p-0' /></div>
            </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
    )
```

This is the child component (CardHolder)

```
const CardHolder = (props) => {
    console.log("Card holder rendered!");

    const headingGradient = ["from-fuchsia-400 to-pink-600", "from-blue-300 to-indigo-500", "from-green-300 to-blue-300", "from-red-400 to-amber-400", "from-pink-400 to-blue-400", "from-orange-300 to-amber-600"];
    const randomIndex = useMemo(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * headingGradient.length), [headingGradient.length]);

    const dragItem = useRef();
    const dragOverItem = useRef();
    const cardTransferFlag = useRef();

    const btnClickHandler = (e) => props.triggerModal(e);

    const msgClickHandler = (e) => props.comments(e);

    return (
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 400 }} transition={{ duration: 1 }} id={`board-${props.index}`} className={cardHolderCSS()}>
            <div className={`w-full min-h-[0.25rem] rounded-t bg-gradient-to-r ${headingGradient[randomIndex]} `}></div>
            <div className="w-11/12 justify-self-center flex items-center justify-between">
                <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-500">{props.title}</h1>
                <button>
                    <FiX className='text-gray-500' onClick={(e) => props.removeBoard(props.index, e)} />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="card-drop !mt-0 h-0 flex opacity-0 p-0 items-center justify-around w-4/5 animate-bounce border border-gray-500 rounded-md shadow-md transition-all ease-in-out" draggable={true} onDrop={e => newBoardCardDrop(e, props.index, props.data, props.changeData)} onDragOver={e => newBoardCardDragOver(e, cardTransferFlag, dragItem, dragOverItem)} onDragLeave={e => newBoardCardDragLeave(e)}>
                <p className='text-gray-700 h-0 md:text-base text-xs'>Place Your Card Here</p>
                <FiCornerRightDown className='text-gray-700 md:scale-110 scale-90 h-0' />
            </div>
            <div className="space-y-3 w-full h-[80%] flex flex-col items-center overflow-y-scroll">
                <AnimatePresence>
                    {props.card?.map((value, i) => <Card key={i} onMsgClick={msgClickHandler} date={value.initiatedDate} participants={value.participants} onBtnClick={btnClickHandler} boardIndex={props.index} boardData={props.data} changeBoardData={props.changeData} index={i} text={value.text} piority={value.piority} dragItem={dragItem} dragOverItem={dragOverItem} cardTransferFlag={cardTransferFlag} />)}
                </AnimatePresence>
            </div>
            <div className="absolute bottom-0 w-full h-10 flex items-center justify-center bg-violet-100 z-30">
                <button className="p-3 flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 justify-between space-x-2" onClick={props.addTaskHandler}><span>Add Task</span> <AiOutlinePlusCircle className='scale-125' /></button>
            </div>
        </motion.div>
    )
}

const compare = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    console.log(prevProps);
    console.log(nextProps);
    return JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps);
}

export default memo(CardHolder, compare);
```

When the boardData state got changed, the prevProps parameter shows the updated state and that is where things go wrong.

I tried to break the below code into a new component and return a Memoized version but that didnt work either.

```
{boardData?.length > 0 ? boardData.map((value, i) => <CardHolder comments={triggerCommentsModal} addTaskHandler={triggerAddCardModal} triggerModal={triggerParticipantsModal} key={value.title} id={value.id} index={i} title={value.title} card={value.cards} removeBoard={removeBoardHandler} changeData={setBoardData} data={boardData} />) : <h1>No boards</h1>}
```

to

```
<WrapperHolder boardData={boardData} triggerCommentsModal={triggerCommentsModal} triggerAddCardModal={triggerAddCardModal} triggerParticipantsModal={triggerParticipantsModal} removeBoardHandler={removeBoardHandler} setBoardData={setBoardData} />
```

Below is the component of WrapperHolder

```
const WrapperHolder = React.memo((props) => {
    return (props.boardData?.length > 0 ? props.boardData.map((value, i) => <CardHolder comments={props.triggerCommentsModal} addTaskHandler={props.triggerAddCardModal} triggerModal={props.triggerParticipantsModal} key={value.title} id={value.id} index={i} title={value.title} card={value.cards} removeBoard={props.removeBoardHandler} changeData={props.setBoardData} data={props.boardData} />) : <h1>No boards</h1>)
})
```

Comment: Why do you need `React.memo`?

Comment: The thing is there are different modals on the parent page and due to the complexity of the application, they have different states. When those state changes, other child components also renders and I want to avoid child rendering.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? Have you measured that it's an issue?

Comment: I won't say it is much of an issue but I want to optimize my application. Without memo my application is working fine but I want to avoid that child rendering.

Comment: As they say, [make it work, make it right, make it fast](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast) and [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) is the root of all evil. Also remember that a child component _updating_ (i.e. React calling the component render function) doesn't mean that anything is necessarily written into the DOM.

Comment: The thing is I just want to avoid child rendering. I want those things to render that needs render, why rendering those things which doesn't need any change?

Comment: Well clearly they _do need_ rendering if memoizing makes things fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but idk that is a valid solution or not. I made a count key of all arrays that are been passed in props. I am also updating those counts as well when the array gets changed.

**The real question was why my compare function was sending me updated props in the first parameter as well?**
When I added the count key-value pair, it is working as expected but in the case of arrays, it is sending me an updated value and that is because of the deep copy and shallow copy. Since arrays come in the shallow copy category, maybe that is why I am getting updated props in the first parameter but when counter was added (deep copy), the results are as expected!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a few child components talking to each other via a common ancestor where I set the states for each of the children but, `useEffect` within the ancestor was re-rendering the wrong child components even when the state had nothing to do with that child component. The dependency array in `useEffect` was not ensuring the other components to not render even if they had nothing to do with that state.

I had to work around by removing many `setState` within `useEffect` because I found out that was a part of the problem. I leveraged `useRef` to mutate my state values and in the child components that rendered unnecessarily, I wrapped the export with

```
export const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(Component)
```